# Can I use microtype locally?

Tags: microtype, bad-box

I have some text which I am not allowed to change, but as it is it produces overfull boxes. Look at the following examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Examples of suitable formats for Transparent copies include
plain ASCII without markup, Texinfo input format, \LaTeX\
input format, SGML or XML using a publicly available DTD,
and standard-conforming simple HTML, PostScript or PDF
designed for human modification.

\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration Site} (or
\enquote{MMC Site}) means any World Wide Web server that
publishes copyrightable works and also provides prominent
facilities for anybody to edit those works. A public wiki
that anybody can edit is an example of such a server. A
\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration} (or
\enquote{MMC}) contained in the site means any set of
copyrightable works thus published on the MMC site.
\end{document}
```

Simply loading the package `microtype` is one suggestion people [have given](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2128) me. I like the effect of that package, but it is global. I don't want to tinker with the rest of the document because of loading the package. So can I use the package locally? I am also okay with not loading `microtype` at all and using default TeX/LaTeX measures for making this text bad-box-free, but in case microtype is the only solution, I would like to use it locally and not globally.

Comment: A possible way that came to my mind was disabling everything that `microtype` changes and writing a custom environment which re-enables the same things locally, so that it will have a limited scope. Another way was to find out what it does in this specific case in (La)TeX-terms and only adding that much code to the text without loading the package.

Comment: Note that a similar question has been asked [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2128).

Comment: Why don't you want to activate `microtype` for your whole document? In my experience it just makes your document look better.

Comment: @Skillmon this text is supposed to be supplied with a package I am writing and I want that package to not have ANY (good/bad) effect on the already existing outputs of people. Smart users will load it anyways, but it should be their choice, not mine ;-)

Comment: and how do you want to make sure that you don't deactivate `microtype` for users that actually want to use it? Also, are you sure that every document you use that with has the same margins?

Comment: I was going to put it in the false branch of `\@ifpackageloaded{microtype}`, but anyways I find [this](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2126#a2369) plain LaTeX solution of yours better, so I am chucking the idea of local `microtype`.

Comment: but thanks anyways for the informative answer as someone else might want to do it just for themselves. So for educational purposes your answer definitely is important.

Comment: Oops, I gave a wrong link. It was supposed to be this one: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2128#a2373

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `microtype` only applies protrusion and font expansion, both can be disabled using `\microtypesetup` (but that must be done after `\AtBeginDocument` so that the two extensions are loaded) and locally re-enabled using the same command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\AtBeginDocument{\microtypesetup{protrusion=false,expansion=false}}

\overfullrule5pt

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true,expansion=true}%
Examples of suitable formats for Transparent copies include
plain ASCII without markup, Texinfo input format, \LaTeX\
input format, SGML or XML using a publicly available DTD,
and standard-conforming simple HTML, PostScript or PDF
designed for human modification.

\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration Site} (or
\enquote{MMC Site}) means any World Wide Web server that
publishes copyrightable works and also provides prominent
facilities for anybody to edit those works. A public wiki
that anybody can edit is an example of such a server. A
\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration} (or
\enquote{MMC}) contained in the site means any set of
copyrightable works thus published on the MMC site.
\par
\endgroup

% just to show that the settings for the rest didn't change

Examples of suitable formats for Transparent copies include
plain ASCII without markup, Texinfo input format, \LaTeX\
input format, SGML or XML using a publicly available DTD,
and standard-conforming simple HTML, PostScript or PDF
designed for human modification.

\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration Site} (or
\enquote{MMC Site}) means any World Wide Web server that
publishes copyrightable works and also provides prominent
facilities for anybody to edit those works. A public wiki
that anybody can edit is an example of such a server. A
\enquote{Massive Multiauthor Collaboration} (or
\enquote{MMC}) contained in the site means any set of
copyrightable works thus published on the MMC site.
\end{document}
```